# How to get all html elements with a fixed starting string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many  html elements  with id
  like

```
        "demo1"
        "demo2"
        "demo3"
```

and many more

```
        "demoNth"
```

how to get all the elemnts using jquery?

Comment: Do they all start with the same word ? ie "demo"

Comment: yes all of them start with the same word

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following :

this will get all elements starting with demo

```
$("[id^=demo]")
```

[Selector documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Iterate over them using each() ->

```
$("[id^=demo]").each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
});
```

[each documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
$("[id^=demo]")
```

Or best way is to use classes

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest giving them a class is the best way.

e.g.

```
<div id="1" class"group">1</div>
<div id="2" class"group">2</div>
<div id="3" class"group">3</div>
<div id="4" class"group">4</div>
```

You can then select all these divs using

$(".group")

Answer (score 2):

`$("element[id^='demo']")` where `element` is your element type.

Comment: If they're using `id`, it's a bit superfluous to include the element.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a selector syntax (`[attrname^=prefix]`) specifically for matching string prefixes.

For a more general purpose solution which will match the ID against an arbitrary regular expression, you should select all elements that *might* match, and then `.filter()` out the ones you actually want, e.g.:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
   return /^demo\d+/.test(this.id);
});
```